# Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress

Tags: iphone, view, controller

I almost broke my brain on this one

Here is the error:
Trying to show status page at the login page
2013-06-30 20:47:53.422 MyProgram[489:907] Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

I have the following code in SCAppDelegate.m

```
- (void)showStatusViewController
{
    MLStatusViewController* statusViewController = [[MLStatusViewController alloc]
                                                   initWithNibName:@"MLStatusViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *topViewCntrller = [self.navController topViewController];
    [topViewCntrller presentModalViewController:statusViewController animated:NO];
}
```

Then I have another view controller where when a user saves data I want to move to another (status) view controller. I don't see how I can add another controller on top so my understanding is if I disband the current one and go back to SCAppDelegate method above that it should show that status page.

This is the code in that view controller that is trying to disband/show status view controller.`enter code here`

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    SCAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate showStatusViewController];
}];
```

I know this comes from the lack of understanding how view controllers work and I read the guide, but still can't seem to figure this out.

I am using Facebook API to login into the app, which is adding some complexity in how to manage view controllers.

Any ideas will be super welcome :D

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add another view controller on top of the existing one by calling pushViewController:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```